# Could not find function "coord_quickmap" in R

Tags: r

I was trying to actually crop part of a country (example is Korea) using this code in R:

```
korea + coord_quickmap(xlim = c(126.5, 128),  ylim = c(35, 37))
```

However, this error appears..

> Error in coord_quickmap(xlim = c(126.5, 128), ylim = c(35, 37)) :
>   could not find function "coord_quickmap"

How can I do this?

Comment: I already tried installing different packages like ggplot2, sf etc but the error is still the same

Comment: where did you get this code? where there any packages they used?

Comment: i was just trying to crop part of a country and i used the estimated coordinates of the place. the country "korea" is already plotted in my program, i just wanted to zoom in a bit.

Answer (score 1):

The `coord_quickmap` function belongs to package `ggplot2`, which is not part of base R. You need to load the library before using it with

```
library(ggplot2)
```

or use the syntax `package::function()` e.g. `ggplot2::coord_quickmap()`.

You may also need to install the package first with `install.packages('ggplot2')`.

Comment: i followed your instruction but this is now the error..    Error in korea + coord_quickmap(xlim = c(126.5, 128), ylim = c(35, 37)) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
In addition: Warning message:
Incompatible methods ("Ops.data.frame", "+.gg") for "+"

Comment: > install.packages('ggplot2')
Error in install.packages : Updating loaded packages

Restarting R session...

> plot(korea + coord_quickmap(xlim = c(126.5, 128),  ylim = c(35, 37)))
Error in coord_quickmap(xlim = c(126.5, 128), ylim = c(35, 37)) : 
  could not find function "coord_quickmap"
> strsplit = TRUE
> plot(korea + coord_quickmap(xlim = c(126.5, 128),  ylim = c(35, 37)))
Error in coord_quickmap(xlim = c(126.5, 128), ylim = c(35, 37)) : 
  could not find function "coord_quickmap"

Comment: This is what happened (see above code).

Comment: ggplot didn't install. are you behind a firewall?

Comment: Hi i checked my C:library and i found ggplot2 there. However, the ggplot2 folder doesn't have coord_quickmap html file there. Do you encountered the same case before? anyone....please help :(

Comment: That is a bad way to check for a function as they can be wrapped in a different function, in this case `coord_map`. If you invoke `?coord_map` you will also bring up the help for `coord_quickmap`.

Comment: i did. found the documentations and tried the contents. but still the same error. "could not find the function coord_quickmap"

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how can i zoom in or crop a part of a country? im a bit hopeless with coord_quickmap -.-